# iPad: launch external application when an application starts

Tags: ipad, events, launch

Is there an API in OSX that I can use to launch my application when users open any app? Something like a global App Launched event?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no meaningful multitasking functionality in iOS API.

Comment: I think there must be one since there're parental control apps you you can buy to lock down features. And it's even built-in utility in  iPad.

Comment: ...What do either of those statements have to do with what I said? There are access control settings in both the iPad and iPhone iOS.  It's part of the operating system.  Multitasking functionality is not.  What you're asking for does not exist.